# function to select combinations of characters from a string in c++

Tags: c++, string, character, combinations

so here is my problem:

I need a function that given a string "qwer" of random length can select and put in an array all the possible sequences of characters long from 1 up to the length of the string.
I am sorry, it is difficult to explain, but i think it should be easier to understand with an example. So if I have the string "qwer", i would like to have a function that create an array with the following entries:

qwer
qwe
wer
qwr
qer
qw
qe
qr
we
wr
er
q
w
e
r

Note that in the items with more than one character, the order of the characters must respect that of the original string (so for instance I want the item qwe but i do not want the idem ewq). It is thus not just a problem of permutations, but of permutations that respect the original order.

Also, as I said at the beginning, ideally the function should be able to handle strings of any length.

Do you know if a function like this exists?
Or do you have any idea about how to create it? I'ma  bit stuck with it..

Comment: _"so here is my problem"_ ib4 _here's my homework_

Comment: `q w e r qq qw qe qr wq ww we wr eq ew ee er rq rw re rr qqq qqw` etc etc. **256** possible sequences!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bathsheba said, we need to substitute characters with bits. And then iterate on all possible values that bits could make. My example works only on short strings with legth less than 31. If you need more, use `std::bitset` container.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> f(const std::string & str)
{
    const int length = str.length();
    const int bits = 1 << length;

    std::vector<std::string> result;
    for (int i = 1; i < bits; ++i)
    {
        std::string combined_string;
        for (int bit = 0; bit < length; ++bit)
        {
            if (i & (1<< bit))
            {
                combined_string += str[bit];
            }
        }
        result.push_back(combined_string);
    }

    return result;
}

void main()
{
    for (auto str : f("qwer"))
    {
       std::cout << str << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way.

1. Associate a 0 or 1 with each letter. A 0 means don't include, 1 means do include.
2. Write the function to map the (binary) number to the string. For example, `0111` will map to `wer`.
3. Build the code to count through the integers from 0 up to the stopping condition (1111, i.e. 15 in your case). Map those integers to binary, and apply (2).